# WCF service and lock keyword

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, using

assume I have a hosted wcf service in a console application like this:

```
public class MyService : IContract
{
  public static readonly object _locker_ = new object();

  public static void DoSomething()
  {
    lock (_locker_)
    {
      //block 1
      DoAnotherWork();
    }
  }

  void IContract.Foo1()
  {
    lock (_locker_)
    {
      //block 2
      DoSomeWork();
    }
  }

  void IContract.Foo2()
  {
    DoSomething();
  }
}
```

does this insures that only one client is in block 1? or block 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static lock object is per-appdomain; so "block 1" and "block 2" only allow a single caller. Ultimately, yes. As long as you only have one appdomain ;p

Note that locks are re-entrant, so the thread with the lock can call the methods again without deadlocking itself (but not via WCF; only via regular C# method calling).

Comment: so can I simply do some synchronization between my clients just with a static lock in my service?

Comment: @HPT if your synchronization means "only one", yes. But! That sounds too coarse-grained if you have lots of callers. You will essentially be processing all the requests separately; there are ways of doing that in WCF by marking with attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You have only one lock, so only one method can obtain the lock at any point in time. You would need separate locks for DoSomeWork and DoAnotherWork if they are to be run in parallel.

Note also that you would need to consider the [InstanceContextMode of your WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx) when considering threading - the default is PerCall.